# Elasticsearch: Index 2GB of documents at once

Tags: elasticsearch

I use the the mapper-attachments-plugin to index and analyze PDFs in my elasticsearch index (1 node, 5 shards). Everything works fine but my problem is the initial import of 1.800 PDFs (about 2GB) from a blob table in a mysql database.

I use the native java client (transport mode), get the documents from my database, encode them as base64 and send them to elasticsearch.
I run into OutOfMemory Errors after about 300 documents. When I give more memory to my import application, the elasticsearch master node is blocked soon after.

Is there a better way to import the documents? Perhaps a "bulk-index-client" or so?

Comment: Do you have some code? It sounds like you're not flushing something in memory.